# Proxy_pass with two variables

Tags: nginx, proxy, lua, proxypass

I need to make a proxy_pass with two variables `$ip` and `$port`. These two variables come from a block lua:

```
location /test/ {
        default_type 'text/plain';
        set $ip '';
        set $port '';

        content_by_lua_block {
            local ip = '';
            local port = '';

            ...

            ngx.var.ip = ip;
            ngx.var.port = port;
        }
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        rewrite ^/connect/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://$ip:$port;
    }
```

When I do this I get a 500 error.

But when I do not go through lua and test without entering a variable in the proxy_pass, it works well:

```
location /test/ {
        default_type 'text/plain';
        set $ip '';
        set $port '';

        content_by_lua_block {
            local ip = '';
            local port = '';

            ...

            ngx.var.ip = ip;
            ngx.var.port = port;
        }
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        rewrite ^/connect/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8008;
    }
```

Comment: In the first example your `ip` and `port` variables are set to an empty string.